# How fast can you “DOCK” the “SHIP”?

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers, letters, word-ladder

You have to reach DOCK from SHIP in the minimum number of tries with the following rules.

You are only allowed to change one letter at a time.
You have to keep the word length the same.

At each step of the way, you must have a legitimate English word. Thus, something like going from "SHIP" to "DHIP" is not a valid step, but from "SHIP" to “SHOP” is valid.

As long as the origin of the word is provided, it can be accepted. To avoid disputes, please stick to well known words.

For example: How do you go from 
S
A
N
E
 to 
H
A
N
D
?

Answer: 
S
A
N
E
→
S
A
N
D
 (1) →
H
A
N
D
 (2).

Done in 2 steps, all real words.

Comment: "In terms of dispute, community will judge the word’s validity." This seems to fit the close reason, *"This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers. See also: [Why are questions off-topic if they invite answers which are not demonstrably correct, or are otherwise speculative?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co)"*

Comment: Then..I will decide on the best answer based on the proof that word exists ..as has been given in some answers..there are always some judgement calls ..in problems like these..there are several paths of words..we are trying to find path with minimum steps..you can always knitpick anything to death,,

Comment: Edited to reduce as much ambiguity as I can..

Comment: What *counts* as a word, though? Do acronyms count? What about words that are archaic, or loanwords that have been used in English only a few times? As long as you do not give precise rules for when something is a word, the question is opinion-based.

Comment: Please refer to previous puzzles of this genre which has garnered enough attention without any problems..I didn’t hear any of your comments for any of those puzzles? you can never give absolutely precise rules....those previous puzzles were well received by the community without this kind of knitpicking...I have stated as best as I can the puzzle so that people can enjoy..if they don’t like, they will downvote and I will move on with the next one

Comment: Actually, this should be closed as standard word ladders are literally a _solved problem_:  http://datagenetics.com/blog/april22019/index.html

Comment: Normally I won’t respond to you.I have to do this for last tIme.. it  is why ..no computer label was put in..you are supposed to be on honors system here..you can google search for anything and solve it..then 90% of the puzzles won’t exist...if people start using algos, searches, writing computer programs..where is the fun in puzzle solving..

Comment: @Uvc Please also consider that this is practically no different from the FIVE -> FOUR puzzle.  There's no twist or anything, it's just more of the same and is easy to propose/create, so I wouldn't have expected a thrillingly positive reception to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5 steps

> SHIP -> [SHUP](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shup) -> SOUP -> [SOUK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/souk) -> SOCK -> DOCK

Note that

> 4 steps is clearly impossible, since there is no valid 1st step from SHIP that changes 1 of the letters to a corresponding letter of DOCK (since DHIP, SOIP, SHCP and SHIK are not valid words).

Comment: That is awesome!

Comment: @Uvc Thank you! Of course, SHUP is clearly debatable, but I've not found anything better.

Comment: You have given the proper link..I will let the community decide on its validity

Comment: [Shik](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Shik) is a word

Answer (score 3):

7 steps:

> SHIP, SHOP, CHOP, COOP, COOK, ROOK, ROCK, DOCK

Comment: You did one better than me. Let us see how all others fare.

Comment: It can be shortened to 6 steps by writing `DOCK-COCK-COOK` etc.

Comment: That is even better

Comment: Proper order should be presented SHIP to DOCK.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in 6 steps

> SHIP
>  SLIP
>  SLAP
>  SOAP
>  SOAK
>  SOCK
>  DOCK

Answer (score 2):

Another 5 stepper using two slightly obscure words!

> SHIP
>  SHOP
>  [SOOP](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/soop)
>  [SOOK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sook)
>  SOCK
>  DOCK

Comment: Note also that dook fits and will probably help you get upvotes from all the ferret fanciers. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1):

7 steps:

> SHIP
>  CHIP
>  CHIN
>  COIN
>  CORN
>  CORK
>  COCK
>  DOCK